# Incorrect syntax parsing :setvar in SQLCMD mode

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, sample-data, adventureworks

I downloaded an AdventureWorks 2012 LT Script from CodeProject, but when I try to run it it says:

> Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing :setvar.

There's nothing more than this:

```
:setvar SqlSamplesDatabasePath   "C:\Program Files\...\DATA\";
:setvar SqlSamplesSourceDataPath "C:\Samples\...\";
```

And yes, I set the SQLCMD mode on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, don't put semi-colons at the end of any SQLCMD lines; this is not T-SQL and is subject to different parser / interpreter rules and syntax.

```
:setvar SqlSamplesDatabasePath   "C:\...\"
:setvar SqlSamplesSourceDataPath "C:\...\"
------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks. I fell foul of this too. Surprisingly, these semicolons are in Microsoft's distribution of AdventureWorks LT 2012 on http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/ : Well, they got that one wrong, didn't they!